# Share phone geolocation coordinates via sms in PhoneGap (for Android/IOS)

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, geolocation

I'm working on a PhoneGap app that would allow a user to share his current location (coordinates) via SMS to his friend.

The process would be:

1. Get current geolocation (in coordinates)
2. Feed coordinates to google maps and create fixed position (a marker/tag) shown in url link to google maps.
3. Send that link (url) to a friend via sms (using the PhoneGap SMS plugin or SMScomposer plugin)
4. The receiver would open the url in sms and be linked to a online google map with a marker showing the location of the sender.

Would somebody be kind enough to give me some directions on where I should start? =)

Regards, Jasha

Answer (score 1):

It is all possible with Phonegap you just have to do a bit of digging.

1. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation
2. http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4part1, http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt4p2
3. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMSPlugin